# how to read specific columns from csv file using python in google collab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-analysis

```py
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['data.csv']))



ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a523fd2e8c08> in <module>()
      1 import io
      2 
----> 3 df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['data.csv']))
      4 
      5 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2155     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2156         try:
-> 2157             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2158         except StopIteration:
   2159             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 77, saw 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd #import pandas
fread =  pd.read_csv('filepath/filename.csv') #make fread as object
freaddf = pd.DataFrame(fread, columns=['col1name', 'col2name', 'col3name'])
print(freaddf.to_string())
```

Comment: Can you add some more useful explanation or make your comments more helpful? The `#import pandas` comment really doesn't tell me anything that the code doesn't tell me, for example.